# How to set the 'category' data type for a pyarrow Table column?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I understand it is possible to retain `category` type when writing a pandas `DataFrame` in a parquet file, using `to_parquet`.

At the start, in my case, I have already a pyarrow `Table`.
Can I set one of its column to have the `category` type?
If yes, how?
(I have not been able to find a hint on Google and pyarrow documentation)

Thanks for any help!
Bests,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In pyarrow, categorical type is called "dictionary type". A pyarrow array can be converted to such a type using the `dictionary_encode()` method:

```py
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> table = pa.table({'a': ['A', 'B', 'A']})
>>> table.schema
a: string

>>> table.column('a')
<pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray object at 0x7f1f94fb9938>
[
  [
    "A",
    "B",
    "A"
  ]
]

>>> table.column('a').dictionary_encode()
<pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray object at 0x7f1f94fb9b48>
[

  -- dictionary:
    [
      "A",
      "B"
    ]
  -- indices:
    [
      0,
      1,
      0
    ]
]
```

To then alter the table with this newly encoded column is a bit more convoluted, but can be done with:

```py
>>> table2 = table.set_column(0, "a", table.column('a').dictionary_encode())
>>> table2.schema
a: dictionary<values=string, indices=int32, ordered=0>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joris! Is there a way to do this when creating the Table from a pyarrow arrays maybe?

Comment: `pa.table({'a': pa.array(['A', 'B', 'A'], pa.string()).dictionary_encode()})`